# dependent: :destroy is not deleting dependencies from views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, has-many-through, has-many

Projects have many rooms. When I delete a project from the view, the associated rooms are not deleted.  Rooms also have many products which should also be deleted when a project is deleted.

Project class

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :rooms
end
```

Projects Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
        @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
        if @project.delete
            redirect_to user_projects_path(@project.user)
        end
    end
end
```

Rooms Controller

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
        @room = Room.find(params[:id])
        if @room.delete
            redirect_to root_path
         end
     end
```

The delete link in the projects show view.

```
 = link_to "Delete", project_room_path(room.project, room), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, title: room.title, class: "btn btn-danger"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the the destroy action to call the destroy method on the instance variable rather than delete.

```
 class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
     @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
     if @project.delete
       redirect_to user_projects_path(@project.user)
     end
   end
 end
```

According to the documentation on [Active Record Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3a%3aAssociations%3a%3aClassMethods-label-Delete+or+destroy?), "*has_many :through associations have records in join tables, as well as the associated records. So ...
... it is assumed that deletion on an association is about removing the link between the owner and the associated object(s), rather than necessarily the associated objects themselves. So with ... has_many :through, the join records will be deleted, but the associated records won't.*"

Comment: Thanks Drew, that fixed the issue. Although I'm still a bit confused. Projects has_many rooms.
The has_many through is on products.  

If I created a Project with rooms but no products. Shouldn't the delete method work in this scenario?

Comment: AFAIK, it depedent: :destroy will call the destroy action on that object. If you you are using delete as the method, it will not call the callbacks, and just delete the associations, not the actual records.